# MacBook Pro wifi not connecting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, macbook-pro, wifi-configuration

I'm having a problem with my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) to connect at the WIFI. The connection is available, but when I click on it, after waiting a while, it appear the diagnosis of connection.

[screenshot of Network Diagnosis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7NAz.png)

After processing that (also if I interrupt it in the middle) and after switching off and on again the WIFI, the MacBook correctly connects to the network.
Unfortunately this solution is not permanent, in fact the next time I try to connect at the WIFI it happens the same.

I'm using an OpenFiber router by Wind (Italy) and I configured a double connection, one for the guests and one for me. Here some screenshots about the 192.168.1.1 configuration:

[Configuration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfOlT.jpg), 
[Configuration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh53T.jpg), 
[Configuration 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43IB9.jpg), 
[Configuration 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j9dW.jpg), 
[Configuration 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnNDB.jpg), 
[Configuration 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zx0H.jpg).

I don't have any problems with the Huawei P10, iPhone 8, iPad, MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011). So this makes me think that the router configuration is fine, but that I have problems with my MacBook Pro.

What can I do to understand

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Go into system preferences, Network, highlight Wifi on the left and then click on advanced bottom right - Remove all the wireless networks. Now click OK, then highlight the wifi on the right again and then click the '-' symbol on the wireless adapter. Restart then go back into system preferences, network, then click the + symbol and add the wireless adapter again. Apply then switch on the wireless adapter and try to rejoin a network.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
This worked for me, at the moment. Let's see if it continues to work.

Comment: Can you accept the answer below? Thankyou

Comment: Please consider marking this question as answered, so other people in their search find it as such.

Comment: Today I had the same problem again. I resolved it again with the same path proposed by @JohnnyVegas, but of corse it is uncomfortable to do it any time more. Do you have maybe any idea on how to fix this problem permanently?

Comment: Create a new login profile and move your data over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into system preferences, Network, highlight Wifi on the left and then click on advanced bottom right.

Remove all the wireless networks. Now click OK, then highlight the wifi on the right again and then click the '-' symbol on the wireless adapter. Restart then go back into system preferences, network, then click the + symbol and add the wireless adapter again.

Apply then switch on the wireless adapter and try to rejoin a network.